# How to limit cpu frequency in OS X?

Tags: performance, power, cpu

The OS X kernel does control this directly since below 5% my CPU gets locked to 1.2GHz instead of the normal 3.7GHz so there has to be a way to control the CPU speed.

I am aware of this question ([Limit processor speed like in Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55964/limit-processor-speed-like-in-windows)) which claimed it to be impossible but after noticing that OS X does control your cpu speed directly depending on battery power I find it hard to believe it's impossible.

So is there any hidden kext and/or kernel call to control the cpu speed? Forwarding me to kernel documentation so I can write my own app is an option as well.

Comment: FYI [duplicate question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55964/limit-processor-speed-like-in-windows) -- you are aware. Check the answers there, it answers your question.

Comment: @chillin: it doesn't answer my question, my question is "How to limit" not whether it's possible or not so if it's impossible than that's not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found this for your reading pleasure:

[Mavericks: Native CPU/IGPU Power Management](http://www.tonymacx86.com/mavericks-desktop-support/128926-mavericks-native-cpu-igpu-power-management.html)

> Native Mavericks power management delivers the best combination of
>   processor and graphics performance and efficiency. The ingredients are
>   an installed processor specific power management ssdt, a compatible
>   system definition and the native power management kext. Native
>   Mavericks power management does not require specific BIOS settings or
>   anything more than one boot setting to load the power management ssdt.
>   Credit for the technique described to PikeRAlpha.
>
> What changed between Mountain Lion and Mavericks power management? The
>   existing processor frequency/power state reporting tools (i.e.,
>   MSRDumper, HWMonitor) stopped reporting power states between idle and
>   max non turbo. This led to an incorrect conclusion that native
>   Mavericks power management was not working. A new tool, Intel Power
>   Gadget, shows Mavericks power management is working as designed.
>
> To be clear, native Mavericks power management is not mandatory. The
>   consequences are not severe. Performance is similar, however, higher
>   temps (~10 C), more power (5-10 W) and sleep problems are likely.
>
> Change Log
>
> v1.1 - 4/4/14 - CPU PM/Core i3/5/7 xxx (1st Generation)/Core 2 and
>   earlier (below) v1.0 - 4/2/14: Initial Release
>
> Requirements
>
> ```
> OS X/10.9.2 or newer
>     Desktop/Laptop only
>     Server, see Guide: Asus X79 OS X Controlled SpeedStep
>
> Stock Clock
>     Verify
>     OC, use ./ssdtPRGen.sh -f freq flag
> ```
>
> Supported CPU/IGPU
>
> ```
> Haswell/HD4600+ (Core i3/5/7 4xxx, 4th Generation)
> Ivy Bridge/HD4000 (Core i3/5/7 3xxx, 3rd Generation)
> Sandy Bridge/HD3000 (Core i3/5/7 2xxx, 2nd Generation)
> ```
>
> Native Mavericks Power Management Recipe
>
> ```
> System Definition - match processor generation/desktop or laptop
> ssdt - custom to installed processor
> kext - native IOPlatformPlugin.kext
> ```
>
> Not considered
>
> ```
> NullCPUPowerManagement.kext
> Safe Mode boot (-x)
> Discrete graphics
> ```

Comment: Very nice, I'll check it out (but I'll have to upgrade to Mavericks first)

Comment: Answers should be selfcontained and not just links.